# Spring Security with multiple roles and Database authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, user-roles

I am trying to develop a Yoga Studio application which gives yoga courses and also sales some yoga products. I have three types of users, 
A customer--can register for a yoga course and also can buy yoga products.
Faculty or Adviser--can do what the customer does plus other things related to the course.
An Admin--can do everything.
I want to implement spring authentication from database(MySQL) where a user can have multiple roles.would anyone please help me on how to do that, preferably without using UserDetailsService Class.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

Comment: what about when somebody is registering as a new user and the system should give it a role by default. Not hard coded role like on the example on the link. Because when a customer registers the system should give him/her a default role. thanks

Comment: Just insert the role when you create the user.